# Listen for a method call

Tags: java

I'm trying to listen to when a method on a class its called.
I have an ArrayList and I want to listen on each item when a method is called (not each method, just the one that I want).

In c# there is something called Action, where I can register methods that will be called when this Action is Invoked, inside a method for example, and also returns parameters to know which item was called etc.

There is something like that in Java?

Comment: Possibly any of the `Consumer` functional interfaces might fit your need (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html), or you can create your own functional interface if you need something more specific (same way you'd create a custom `delegate`in C#)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at AspectJ (https://www.baeldung.com/aspectj). It allows you to define pointcuts that match your method so that a given code (the advice) is run when your method is called.

Comment: Not really looking to add any library. Does not really anything like this exist in Java? I just want to check when a method is called and do something then

Comment: No, it does not. The only option is to develop the solution yourself.